# How do I enable my Wordpress website RSS feed? My site doesn't seem to have an RSS feed

Tags: rss

I need the RSS feed on my site but it doesn't seem to have one. All the articles I've read say Wordpress sites have a default RSS feed so I must be doing something wrong.

To try to find my feed, I've already tried:

http://wowitinc.com/?feed=rss
http://wowitinc.com/?feed=rss2
http://wowitinc.com/?feed=atom
http://wowitinc.com/feed/
http://wowitinc.com/feed/rss/
http://wowitinc.com/feed/rss2/
http://wowitinc.com/feed/atom/

All of the above simply refresh my site back to the homepage.

I also tried Google FeedBurner with www.wowitinc.com and received:

"We could not find a valid feed at that address."

"The URL does not appear to reference a valid XML file. We encountered the following problem: Error on line 234: Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character."

I have access to my cPanel but I really don't know what else to look for. I expect I need to add/modify some code. But can anyone advise where I should be looking and what I should do?

I'm lost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you have to edit the `functions.php` file of your theme.

Try to find a `[themename]_setup` function (according to WordPress code conventions) inside the `functions.php` file of your active theme and add the following code in it:

```
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
```

This code will add the RSS feed links to HTML `<head>` of all pages.

You can find more information here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Automatic_Feed_Links

Comment: Thank you, Rayat.  I found the code in my functions.php but it already includes the line of code you suggested.  So it would appear my theme is ready to cooperate with RSS but something else isn't.

Comment: Then may be somewhere in your theme or plugin there is something not allowing RSS feeds. If you have any SEO plugin installed e.g. Yoast plugin. You should check its RSS feeds settings.

Comment: UPDATE - SUCCESS!  Rayat's mention of plugins prompted me to turn off ALL of them and then turn them on one-by-one, checking Google FeedBurner after each activation.  Although I could not find an offending plugin (I turned all the same ones back on), my feed is now working.  Rayat - your rock!